# MYSQL PHP: How can i find total no. of columns in a Row?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from formtable") or die("Records could not be fetched");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))  
    { 
           echo $row[0].$row[1].$row[2];
    }
```

The above code runs perfect. But i find this statement -> `echo $row[0].$row[1].$row[2]` bit too static. Because if a new column is added i will have to modify the code as `echo $row[0].$row[1].$row[2].$row[3]`.

So, How can i count total columns of the row in order to avoid such a problem?

Comment: Reena do you want the column values or you want the total number of rows in table?

Comment: print_r($row) something for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use something like:-

```
foreach($row AS $column)
{
echo $column;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use count($row) to find the number of fields. But it is better to use a foreach loop as previously suggested.

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_num_fields()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-fields.php) is what you're looking for.

Just to not leave it unspoken; the `mysql_*` family functions are deprecated, for new code you should use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Downvoter, how is this not an answer to `How can i find total no. of columns in a Row?`?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it make more sense to use something like this:

```
echo implode($row);
```

No need to use a loop when there's a function that does it for you...